# Javascript: call dialog from button

Tags: javascript, button, dialog

I hope you can help me, because i'm new at javascript.
I want to open a dialog by clicking on an  button. 
When it shows up and you click "OK", there should pop-up a second dialog.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1962249.aspx?Make+a+button+open+a+javascript+dialog

And also on stackoverflow i saw related questions. But none of them could answer my question: What do I wrong or what should I do to make it work?

My Code is:

```
    <!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
      $(function() {
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog(
       {
        autoOpen:false,
        maxHeight: 250,
        maxWidth: 600,
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check"},
            click: function() 
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
            }
        },

        {
            text: "Cancel",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-close"},
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
    });
    $( "#dialog2" ).dialog(
    {   
        autoOpen: false,
        maxHeight: 400,
        maxWidth: 600,
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check"},
            click: function() 
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $("#dialog3").dialog("open");
            }
        },

        {
            text: "Cancel",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-close"},
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
    });
    $( "#dialog3" ).dialog(
    {   
        autoOpen: false,
        maxHeight: 400,
        maxWidth: 600,
        buttons: [
        {
            text: "Ok",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-check"},
            click: function() 
            {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $("#dialog3").dialog("open");
            }
        },

        {
            text: "Cancel",
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-close"},
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
    });
  });
  $function myFunction(){
    $( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Tekst</p>
</div>

 <div id="dialog2" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>Tekst</p>
</div>

 <div id="dialog3" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Test.</p>
</div>

<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunction()" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Click Here</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register the `click` handler as this:

```
$( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Inside the `domReady` function where you are already creating the dialogs.

And remove this part:

```
$function myFunction(){
    $( "#btn1" ).click(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
}
```

And in the `input` element remove the `onclick` attribute.

```
<button id="btn1" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Click Here</button>
```

You have to do the same for each button/dialog combination.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56nf0cnk/)

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple syntax issues with your code. Full fix is here http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Main issue was the call to the btn1 click function

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```